# Bootstrap positioning Dropdown next to searchbar

Tags: dropdown

I want to position 2 dropdowns side by side next to a searchbar I have but I can only position them under it. I hope someone can help me. Below is my code

```
<div>
<div class="input-group">
<div class="icon-addon">
     <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control"
               placeholder='Type to filter the table...'>

<label style="z-index: 22" for="search" class="fa fa-search" rel="tooltip" 
title="search"></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

<select class="form-control" style="width: 105px;">
<option>Festpreis</option>
<option>Stundenbasis</option>

</select>
```

Comment: You show here only one drop-down. Where is the second one? It is not clear what you want to reach.

Answer (score 0):

heres the code for it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Vojtěch Matras">
  <title>Admin Express Blogs&Magazines</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2"><input type="text" id="search" class="form-control"
      placeholder='Type to filter the table...'></div>
    <div class="col-2"> <select>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select> </div>
    <div class="col-2"> <select>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select> </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

you can check in fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a006rj3n/     resize the browser window to see responsiveness

Comment: @jizang its better to use dropdowns in grid system of bootstrap although you did not add  the second dropdown

Comment: yeah i just copied my code with one dropdown. I did try to divide it with col md.. but still it is under my searchbar

Comment: @Jizang u take my code and copy it  and try it i have showed you in the fiddle  its works perfectly

Comment: if it solved your problem give an upvote and give it a green tick